# How do I check what files I have permission to read in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I can see an individual file's permissions with `ls -l`.

In the case where there are hundreds or thousands of files in a directory - most of which I can't read, how do I check which files I have permission to read?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try that** :

```
for i in *; do test -r "$i" && echo "$i is readable for $USER"; done
```

See `help test`

**You can also do** (`bash test`) :

```
for i in *; do [[ -r "$i" ]] && echo "$i is readable for $USER"; done
```

See `man bash | less +/'\[\[ expression'`

**Or with `POSIX shell`** :

```
for i in *; do [ -r "$i" ] && echo "$i is readable for $USER"; done
```

See `help [`

**Finally**

`&&` is a *shortcut* (boolean **AND**) for `if condition; then action; fi`

Answer (score 2):

You can use stat(1) to discover file permissions.